# undefined function __set_state in smarty 3 template

Tags: php, smarty3

I'm trying to move from Smarty 2 to 3

I get error like this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::__set_state() in ....

Problem occurs only if I enable smarty caching for that page. If I disable cache then all works fine.

Here is part of compiled smarty cache file where problem occurs:

```
<div > 
  <?php echo insert_quickorderMenuLinks(array ( 
  'category' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array( 
     'category_id' => '4633', 
     'site_type_id' => '17', 
     'name' => 'Shop', 
     'parent_category_id' => '4569', 
  )), 
  'shop_group_id' => '25', 
  ),$_smarty_tpl);?> 
</div>
```

Can somebody tell me what is wrong here and how to fix ? 
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe deleting the cache files and the compiled templates would help? Maybe they are not compitable with each other.. Smarty 3 using cache files generated from Smarty 2...

Comment: Deleting cache or compiled files does not help

Comment: It seems that you are maybe calling `var_export` somewhere in your code? Have a look what parameters you are giving to the function `insert_quickorderMenuLinks`...